NAMD simulation NPT pressure fluctuation
I've made a simulation in NAMD in NPV.The pressure mean Is equal 1 but there Is a great fluctuation of values how can i fix It?

Welcome and thank you for the question. This question has been answered multiple times in the forum. You can have a look here - https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/large-pressure-fluctuations-in-molecular-dynamics/4641#4641
